# Is there a way to use regex to surround words with double quotes with find & replace in VS code?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I have output that looks like a `JSON` object and would like to pretty print it. I have the plugin to pretty print it but I can only do so if the output has double quotes in the words, which my output doesn't (see example below). Is there a way to do so with regex provided by Visual Studio Code or do I have to learn how to get a script to do this for me?

```
{a: b, c: [], d: {e: f} }
```

Desired output:

```
{"a": "b", "c": [], "d": {"e": "f"} }
```

Which `vscode-json:Beautify` can pretty print later provide indentation like:

```
{
    "a": "b", 
    "c": [], 
    "d": {
       "e": "f"
    } 
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

Comment: `"[]"` are you sure?

Comment: @depperm, I put `""` everywhere. Updating question.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, does this mean that vs code regex can't do it as you  suggest `JSON.stringify` that would need a script or does Vs code accept that somewhere?

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that with VSCode. But if you know vim, you can use vim plugin accomplish that. In vim I would do while putting my cursor on a word: `ciw<Esc>p`. You can also record that in a macro and reuse it.

Comment: Notepad++ does a great job with regex search and replace as well.  Are you trying to put quotes around all alphanumeric sequences, or is it more complicated than that?

Comment: sequences with alphanumeric characters and an underscore

Comment: In Notepad++ it's just Find what: `(\w+)` and Replace with: `"\1"` and then press Replace All.  It may be similar in vscode.

Comment: VScode is slightly different,  use `"$1"` as replacement text and `(\w+)` for find.   It may also be possible to use `\w+` for find  and `"$0"` for replacement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In VSCode Search and Replace:

`\w+`  for the search argument

`"$0"` for the replace argument

and press "replace all"

Comment: If I wanted to omit just numbers, what would I enter instead?

Comment: @heretoinfinity you are getting fancier regex then.  If your alpha had no digits in it at all, you could use `[A-Za-z_]+` as a search argument, but it would not put quotes around a symbol like `A1C`  I use `www.regex101.com` to test regex patterns.  You could exclude patterns starting with a digit using a search argument like `[A-Za-z_]\w*` which would match anything that started with letter or underscore, but still won't match `100abc`

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this, you can simply select the Regular Expression and

then search for

```
".*."
```